# How can i set line spacing in web view?

Tags: android

How should i make line spacing in web view?
I had load data in web view by string like this `String p = <html><body>hey</body></html>`

```
webview.loaddata(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you have to do it in your html or css, there is no control over line spacing in webview.